# I get an error when deactivate a stake account

Tags: web3.js, solana-cli, javascript, cli, stake

I get this error

> SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid instruction data
> at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\Users\jlavo\node_modules@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:8026:13)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\Users\jlavo\node_modules@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:7992:20)
> at async Connection.sendTransaction (C:\Users\jlavo\node_modules@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:7983:12)
> at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\Users\jlavo\node_modules@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:2160:21)
> at async main (C:\Users\jlavo\Documents\solana-withdrawal\withdrawStake.js:56:26) {
> logs: [
> 'Program Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
> 'Program Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111 failed: invalid instruction data'
> ]
> }

In this code

```
const {
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  Account,
  SystemProgram,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  Transaction,
  TransactionInstruction,
} = require('@solana/web3.js');

// Function to get user input
async function getUserInput(prompt) {
  const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    readline.question(prompt, (answer) => {
      readline.close();
      resolve(answer);
    });
  });
}

// Asynchronous main function
async function main() {
  // Initialize Solana connection for Mainnet
  const connection = new Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com', 'confirmed');

  // Prompt user for wallet private key
  const privateKey = await getUserInput('Enter your wallet private key: ');
  const wallet = new Account(Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex'));

  // Prompt user for stake account public key
  const stakeAccountPublicKeyStr = await getUserInput('Enter your stake account public key: ');
  const stakeAccountPublicKey = new PublicKey(stakeAccountPublicKeyStr);

  // Get recent blockhash
  const blockhash = (await connection.getRecentBlockhash('max')).blockhash;

  // Create a custom stake account deactivation instruction
  const deactivateInstruction = new TransactionInstruction({
    programId: new PublicKey('Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111'), // Update with the correct StakeProgramId
    keys: [
      { pubkey: wallet.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
      { pubkey: stakeAccountPublicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
    ],
    data: Buffer.alloc(0), // No additional data required
  });

  // Build a transaction containing the deactivation instruction
  const deactivateTx = new Transaction().add(deactivateInstruction);

  // Sign and send the transaction
  const deactivateTxId = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, deactivateTx, [wallet]);
  console.log(`Stake account deactivated. Tx Id: ${deactivateTxId}`);

  // Prompt user for withdrawal amount
  const withdrawalAmount = await getUserInput('Enter the amount to withdraw (in SOL): ');

  // Withdraw funds from the stake account
  const withdrawTx = SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: stakeAccountPublicKey,
    toPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
    lamports: withdrawalAmount * 1e9, // Convert SOL to lamports
  });

  const withdrawTxId = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, withdrawTx, [wallet]);
  console.log(`Stake account withdrawn. Tx Id: ${withdrawTxId}`);

  // Confirm that the stake account balance is now 0
  const stakeBalance = await connection.getBalance(stakeAccountPublicKey);
  console.log(`Stake account balance: ${stakeBalance / 1e9} SOL`);

  // Close the connection or perform any necessary cleanup
  // connection.close(); // Uncomment if needed
}

// Call the asynchronous main function
main().catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Why do you set the instruction data to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things to fixup here.

First the data for a deactivate instruction is actually `[5, 0, 0, 0]`, given by the index at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/35de86bcc20a751ec4d30bbe0788b402b43f2eb9/packages/library-legacy/src/programs/stake.ts#L538 as a 32-bit unsigned int.

You'll also need to pass in the clock sysvar and reorder the accounts, which gives:

```
const deactivateInstruction = new TransactionInstruction({
    programId: new PublicKey('Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111'),
    keys: [
      { pubkey: stakeAccountPublicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
      { pubkey: SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
      { pubkey: wallet.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: false },
    ],
    data: Buffer.from([5, 0, 0 ,0]),
  });
```

You'll run into issues later, since you can't immediately withdraw stake from an activate stake account. And to withdraw from a stake account, you must use the `StakeProgram.withdraw` instruction instead of `SystemProgram.transfer`. But this should get you started.

And as mentioned in the other answer, it's much easier to just use the bindings at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/35de86bcc20a751ec4d30bbe0788b402b43f2eb9/packages/library-legacy/src/programs/stake.ts#L920

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to build the transaction from scratch, use [the method available](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/StakeProgram.html#deactivate) in the @solana/web3.js package.